# Making requests in iOS SDK, loops flys through too fast

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I have an array of friend ID's that I'd like to call and then store the returned data object.

Looks something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.friendIDArray.count; i++){

            self.detailedRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[self.friendIDArray objectAtIndex:i] andDelegate:self];
        }
```

The problem is I guess I'm sending out requests far too frequently, and not giving FB a chance in returning the data back properly? How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do.  This very closely mimics how you make asynchronous requests with the NSURLConnection API.

In your header/.h file create a class attribute (member variable, whatever you want to call it)

```
//header/.h file
int indexOfLastFriendLoaded;
```

In your implementation file:

```
- (void) loadFriend:(int) indexOfFriendToLoad {
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[self.friendIDArray objectAtIndex:indexOfFriendToLoad] andDelegate:self];
}

//this method is called when each facebook request finishes,
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    //first do whatever you need to with "result" to save the loaded friend data

    //We make the next request from this method since we know the prior has already completed.
    if (indexOfLastFriendLoaded < [self.friendIDArray count]) {
        [self loadFriend:indexOfLastFriendLoaded];
        indexOfLastFriendLoaded++;
    }   
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    //initialize facebook object first

    indexOfLastFriendLoaded = 0;
    [self loadFriend:indexOfLastFriendLoaded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the requests api suggests you make a delegate to deal with the results.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/FBRequestDelegate/

Comment: I do, I use the didLoad method but it only executes like once at the end. I think because my loop sends out requests too quickly, messing with the response?

Comment: try something  like this http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1269-sleep-equivalent-iphone.html  well as long as you are not in the app delegate